# Find unsubcribed subcriptions id from Exchange Web services

Tags: c#, web-services, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I am using Exchange web services (Exchange server 2010) to synchronize user's outlook calendar with my application.I implemented EWS Push Notifications to call back my application whenever events are created ,modified ,deleted by out look users. I achieved this by subscribing user's email credentials  with EWS.

Client application should send OK responses to server whenever it get callbacks from the server .If there are no OK responses from client application for some time the particular subscription will be automatically unsubscribed.

If client is unreachable for some time due to any unexpected reason i need to subscribe only unsubscribed users instead of subscribing all the users.

My issue now is how to get unsubscribed users/Or subscriptions Id's  from EWS?I couldn't find anything helpful regarding this in MSDN documentation.

Any one knows?

MSDN Reference
[enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458791%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only way to do this is to make use of the `StatusEvent`
 (I call it the *heartbeat*).  When you subscribe, you set a parameter to indicate how often EWS is to POST to your Push HTTP listener.  (I use 3 minutes--YMMV.)  So after 3 minutes (plus a little extra to be sure), if you don't hear from EWS, either by a `StatusEvent` or some other "real" event for a subscription, then you should re-subscribe for that user.

Comment: Thank you.Yes i was also thinking to use Status event to log a time stamp .And if i couldn't hear more than 3 min from the EWS then i need to subscribe it again with particular user.But I am wondering why EWS is not keeping any references to the unsubscribe id's ?Because it is now keeping subscribed ids so that it can call back to client.

Comment: I think it's just a question of conserving resources.  If it can't send you a notification after 4 tries, it gives up on you and moves on to those it can contact.  Keep in mind that the Client Access Servers are somewhat unreliable--I've seen many cases where they crash or otherwise discard subscriptions.  With Exchange Online, it gets real crazy.  Even with things like Streaming Notifications, it's the app's (i.e. YOUR) responsibility to detect when a subscription might not be getting what's expected and re-subscribe.